# JHipster - Jenkins - Continues Integration Issue

Tags: spring, jenkins, jhipster

I'm trying to do some continues integration with JHipster and Jenkins CI. First, in my application I have `Jenkins file` with specified commands.

I have setted CI server with Jenkins installed and its plugins.

Now I want after build and back-end tests to deploy app on my testing server. I have created pipeline from bitbucket to jenkins that triggers every time that I commit change to master branch.

This is content of my jenkins file:

```
node {
    // uncomment these 2 lines and edit the name 'node-4.4.5' according to what you choose in configuration
    // def nodeHome = tool name: 'node-4.4.5', type: 'jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation'
    // env.PATH = "${nodeHome}/bin:${env.PATH}"

    stage 'check environment'
    sh "node -v"
    sh "npm -v"
    sh "bower -v"
    sh "gulp -v"

    stage 'checkout'
    checkout scm

    stage 'npm install'
    sh "npm install"

    stage 'clean'
    sh "./mvnw clean"

    stage 'backend tests'
    sh "./mvnw test"

    stage 'packaging'
    sh "./mvnw package -Pprod -DskipTests"
}
```

Here is my configuration: https://jpst.it/QKcn

Do I need to modify `Jenkins file` or to do something else?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no deploy stage. But before proceeding: Does all run through without errors till 'packaging'?

Comment: And packaging works fine... I just need a deploy stage...

Comment: @HubertSchumacher Do you have an idea how to make deploy stage?

Comment: I never digged into this as I'm manually uploading my package files..sorry

Comment: Does anyone else has an idea?

Comment: @Heril, I have error on **mvnw** clean stage with error `connection timeout` error, How can i proceed

Comment: @Venkat try mvn instead of mvnw

Comment: @Venkat or better, remove clean stage and then in packaging stage set command **./mvnw clean package -Pprod -DskipTests** or **mvn clean package -Pprod -DskipTests**

Comment: @Herin, Thanks it works fine but why **mvnw package -Pprod -DskipTests** doesn't works and **mvn package -Pprod -DskipTests** works

Comment: @Venkat that is some kind of Maven Wrapper. **mvnw** allows you to run the Maven project without having Maven installed and present on the path. I prefer to use **mvn** instead of mvnw.